# Draw on the image instead of image view in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I am working on a drawing board app. I would like to implement a "pen" that draw on the image.

And so far I have create a custom imageview:

```
public class CustomDraw extends ImageView {

    private int color = Color.BLACK;
    private float width = 4f;
    private List<Holder> holderList = new ArrayList<Holder>();

    private class Holder {      
        Path path;
        Paint paint;

        Holder(int color, float width) {
            path = new Path();
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
            paint.setColor(color);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        }
    }

    public CustomDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        holderList.add(new Holder(color, width));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Holder holder : holderList) {
            canvas.drawPath(holder.path, holder.paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                holderList.add(new Holder(color,width));
                holderList.get(holderList.size() - 1).path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                holderList.get(holderList.size() - 1).path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void resetPaths() {
        for (Holder holder : holderList) {
            holder.path.reset();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBrushColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
        }
}
```

The problem is , how can I draw on the image actually but not the imageview? That means, I should not able to draw outside the image, and when I zoom the view, the content should be zoom accordingly.  I have found and attempt using the extend drawable but it seems I can not draw at run time.

Thanks

Comment: See this example [Draw on Picture and Save](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/DrawonPictureandsave.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should possibly use `SurfaceView` instead. It is more advanced compared to `ImageView`.

Refer to this for drawing: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/

This is for zoom:
http://android-innovation.blogspot.co.nz/2013/07/how-to-implement-pinch-and-pan-zoom-on.html

Comment: extend surfaceview instead of imageview? then everything is nearly the same?